# SQL Server: compare value before insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to insert data from an API into my table in Azure server. I want to filter the rate value is greater than or equal 13.6 before insertion. My query below somehow does not work and got the syntax error for the IF condition:

```
DECLARE @end DATE
SET @end = (SELECT GETDATE())

INSERT INTO [dbo].[rule] (status, start, [end], type, 
                          originalAmount, availableAmount, fulfilledAmount, 
                          rate, periodMin, periodMax, created, api_key_id)
VALUES (@status, @start, @end, @type, 
        @originalAmount, @availableAmount, @fulfilledAmount, 
        @rate, @periodMin, @periodMax, @created, @api_key_id)

IF (@rate >= 13.6)
```

Comment: Gordon's answer is the clearest solution.   However, you could replace your IF above with WHERE, i.e.    WHERE (@rate >= 13.6)

Comment: Take a read of this, chap. It will show you how to use an IF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

Comment: thank you all for your tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Declare @end DATE;
SET @end=getdate());

IF (@rate >= 13.6)  
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[rule]
        (status, start, [end], type, originalAmount, availableAmount, fulfilledAmount, rate, periodMin, periodMax, created, api_key_id)
      VALUES
        (@status, @start, @end, @type, @originalAmount, @availableAmount, @fulfilledAmount, @rate, @periodMin, @periodMax, @created, @api_key_id);
END;
```

Comment: Hi, after insertion, my table row is not in the right order as before. How can I maintain the row order, and just add new row into the table? For example, the column 'type' always has 2 values: 'BID' or 'ASK'. I want the 'BID' row always keeps on top after every insertion from API data constantly.

Comment: I made a separate question here, I wish you have time to look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705439/ms-sql-sorting-after-insertion . Thank you

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn . . . Tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want data in a particular order for a result set, you need to include an `ORDER BY` in the query.

Comment: a comment by @Used_By_Already:  "Relational databases do not store the rows of a table in the manner you are assuming. It will not manke youto be constantly reirganizing the data". I think he is right.